# How to use infinite series to bound $\pi$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, approximation, pi

Given that:

$\pi = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16^k}\left(\frac{4}{8k+1} - \frac{2}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right)$ and $0 \le\left(\frac{4}{8k+1} - \frac{2}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right) \le 4$ for all $k$, estimate the number of terms in the series required to approximate $\pi$ within $\frac{1}{1024}$.

I know from the definition of convergence that if we let $s_n =\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{16^k}\left(\frac{4}{8k+1} - \frac{2}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right)$, that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for all $n\ge N$, $|s_n - \pi|<\epsilon$.
We want to find $N$ such that  $|s_n-\pi| <\frac{1}{1024}$.

I tried to use the bound to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{1}{16^k}\left(\frac{4}{8k+1} - \frac{2}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right) \le \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{1}{4^{2k-1}} = \frac{4}{15}\left(1-\frac{1}{16^N}\right)$. But I am not really sure where to go from here since that doesn't really link to the convergence to pi.

Any hints on how to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: What you really want to do is bound 
$$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \left| \frac{1}{16^{k}} \left(\frac{4}{8k+1} - \frac{2}{8k+4} - \frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right) \right|$$
and find $N$ so that this $< 1/(1024)$.

Comment: So should I use $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{16^k}\left(\frac{4}{8k+1} - \frac{2}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right)| \le  \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{4^{2k-1}}| \le \int_{N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{2x-1}} dx$?

Comment: No need to use an integral.  $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty 1/4^{2k-1}$ is a geometric series.

Comment: What's the motivation for starting from k = N+1, instead of k =0?

Comment: The sum from $0$ to $\infty$ is $\pi$.  The sum from $0$ to $N$ is the partial sum $s_N$.  The difference $\pi - s_N$ is the sum from $N+1$ to $\infty$.